# sql query to calculate total working hour from same Login/Logout column in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date difference between two records in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449496/date-difference-between-two-records-in-same-table)

I am new to MS Access, Know a little SQL and this is my first question here. before asking question I have searched a lot to find a suitable solution. Here's the scenario:

I have a table  with the following structure: 
RCDID-- EmployeeID-- LogDate-- LogTime-- terminalID-- InOut
1 -----------2001---------1/4/2012---15:39:27----iGuard3A-----IN
2 -----------2023---------1/4/2012---15:45:27----iGuard3A-----IN
3 -----------2001---------1/4/2012---15:47:29----iGuard3A-----Out

final requirement is to get the total working time for each employee id for every month. main problem is the login and log out time is on different records. but i already did that, i mean i wrote the sql  to have another calculated for every login logout time interval. with some other criteria my sql is as follows:

```
SELECT AccessLog.EmployeeID, 
       AccessLog.LogDate, 
       AccessLog.TerminalID, 
       AccessLog.LogTime,   
       Format((SELECT MAX(LogTime) 
               FROM AccessLog AS Alias  
               WHERE Alias.LogTime < AccessLog.LogTime 
               AND Alias.EmployeeID = AccessLog.EmployeeID 
               AND Alias.LogDate = AccessLog.LogDate 
               AND AccessLog.TerminalID <> "iGuard1A" 
               AND AccessLog.TerminalID  <> "iGuard1B" 
               AND AccessLog.EmployeeID LIKE "2*"),"hh:nn:ss") AS PrevTime,
       Format((ElapsedTime([PrevTime],[LogTime])),"hh:nn:ss") AS Duration,
       AccessLog.InOut
FROM AccessLog
WHERE AccessLog.TerminalID <> "iGuard1A" 
AND AccessLog.TerminalID <> "iGuard1B" 
AND AccessLog.EmployeeID LIKE "2*" 
AND AccessLog.InOut = "OUT"
ORDER BY AccessLog.EmployeeID, AccessLog.LogDate, AccessLog.LogTime;
```

It turned out to be a complex query to me. but because this is the first time i m working on access, i wasn't aware about everything from the beginning. I calculated the prevtime and used it as login time for the corresponding logout time records.

Now my goal is to calculate the total duration for each employee id. I used this following code. but it needs the group by clause which i m not sure about.

```
Format((Sum([Duration])-Int(Sum([Duration]))),"hh:nn:ss") AS TotalTime
```

this total time will be based on every month.

any help will be appreciated. am i on the wrong path. should  i have used vba and report for this purpose?

Comment: I believe you will have an easier time handling this in VBA.  (You said "vba and report" -- I don't know what you mean by report.)  There is probably a way using SQL, but in my experience developing and trouble shooting such a solution is much easier in VBA.

Comment: You really ought to define a table that lists the excluded terminals (`Ignore_Terminal` or some such), which will make it much easier to exclude/include terminals in the future.  You may want to restrict the rows selected in the sub-query to just login times, to reduce rows queried; you also don't need `AND AccessLog.EmployeeId LIKE "2*"` in the subquery.  You shouldn't be formatting time in SQL, leave that to the display code.

Comment: Possible duplicates:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1276521/122139

http://stackoverflow.com/q/6952106/122139

http://stackoverflow.com/q/5449496/122139

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6326480/122139

Comment: If you want the total per employee, you can only select the employee and the total.  You shouldn't need to do any subtraction, that I'm aware of.

Comment: Table `AccessLog` has separate fields for `LogDate` and `LogTime`.  Can they be combined into a single Date/Time field?

Comment: @HansUp this is the table i got from the client,  i cant change the table structure or create a new table.

Comment: What is `ElapsedTime()` ... a VBA user-defined function?

Comment: @HansUp , yes its a VBA user defined function.

all I need now is to sum up the duration column for each employee(may be by Group By employee), but i m not able to do any group by as other fields used in the query also have to be included in group by. I m not sure if i m getting it right.

Comment: But Duration is a string formatted as "hh:nn:ss".  How do you intend to sum it?

Comment: @HansUp converting the duration to seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follows, but the query is taking too much time, almost a minute. I think its because of many times of conversion. any idea how can i optimize this query. which function is faster for time conversion? the data type for logtime in table is date/time, should i change it to any other type like text?

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       month(LogDate), 
       SUM(int(DateDiff("s",  '00:00:00',Duration))) AS abc
       FROM (SELECT AccessLog.EmployeeID, 
                    AccessLog.LogDate, 
                    AccessLog.TerminalID, 
                    AccessLog.LogTime, 
                    Format((SELECT max(LogTime) 
                          FROM AccessLog AS Alias 
                          WHERE Alias.LogTime < AccessLog.LogTime 
                                AND Alias.EmployeeID = AccessLog.EmployeeID 
                                AND Alias.LogDate = AccessLog.LogDate 
                                AND (Alias.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
                                And (Alias.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B"  
                                AND Alias.EmployeeID = AccessLog.EmployeeID),
                    "hh:nn:ss")  AS PrevTime, 
                    Format((ElapsedTime(iif(PrevTime = '',logtime,prevtime),[LogTime])),"hh:nn:ss") AS Duration, 
                    AccessLog.InOut 
            FROM AccessLog 
            WHERE (((AccessLog.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
            And (AccessLog.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B") 
            AND ((AccessLog.EmployeeID) Like "2*") 
            AND ((AccessLog.InOut)="OUT")) 
ORDER BY AccessLog.EmployeeID, AccessLog.LogDate, AccessLog.LogTime) 
GROUP BY EmployeeID, month(LogDate);
```